# How to remove warning messages in R Markdown document?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

I have an R Markdown document, which takes a really long time to knit because of heavy computations. Mistakenly there are some code chunks where I forgot to put `warnings=False` before knitting the document. Is their any way to remove those warning messages, without knitting the document again??
Is there any way to remove warnings from the Markdown document and rebuild an html file from the markdown. I don't want to execute the code again.
Need the similar changes in the markdown document as well.

Comment: You can always edit the resulting html file.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I also need similar changes in the markdown document.

Answer (score 86):

If you want to turn off messages and warnings in the whole document you can use this code chunk right after the yaml portion.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE} 
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning = FALSE, message = FALSE) 
```
````

Comment: this didnt work for me with flexdashboard

Answer (score 10):

1. To fix the `.Rmd` to stifle all warnings entirely, in the initial setup chunk in the document, add ```` ```{r setup, warning=FALSE} ````
2. For your post-knit HTML document you can always just open it in the browser, like chrome for instance, right-click on the warning then choose `select element` to see the HTML that makes up the displayed warning and then remove that from the HTML file without having to knit the R Markdown again.