# R Notebook how to prevent messages when loading packages

Tags: r, rnotebook

I have created the following R Notebook in RStudio:

````
---
title: "test"
author: "by me"
date: 'last updated: Jan 23, 2022'
output:
  html_notebook:
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
    number_sections: yes
    highlight: haddock
---

# First headline

## Packages don't load quietly

```{r}
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = F, quietly = T)
```
````

Now, irrespective if I just preview the file (which I understand is the html notebook file) or if I knit it to html I get the full babbling when loading the package. If I just "preview" I only get it the first time I preview. When knitting to html, the all messages always appear.

(BTW: if someone could explain to me the differences between the "preview" version and "knit to HTML", that would be great.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60275813/11485370 Try this solution?

Comment: Yes, it does indeed. Thank you! I won't use it for the whole file, but my workaround now would be to create one line of code where I say `{r eval = FALSE}`, so that it does show the respective code in the output, and then the same code again, but this time with `{r include = FALSE}`, so that it does load the packages, but doesn't show the code in the html.

Answer (score 1):

you can try `{r message=FALSE}`.